# I got empty response when I called IEconService of Steam API using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, steam

I want to list all my trade history but I may do something wrong.

I call this IEconService/GetTradeHistory API

> https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeHistory/v1/?key={{API Key}}&format=json&navigating_back=1&get_descriptions=1&include_failed=1&include_total=1

and this is what I got

```
{
    "response": {
    }
}
```

I have checked in the trade history from client interface, there are 2 as shown below:

[image: here]

I tried to call another API which is not about IEconService it works properly.

Ps.

- I have tried to use domain name that same as the registered API.
- I have tried to login to steam OpenID connect using passport-openid package but it was not work.
- I use "request" package to call API but it was not work too.
- It was not work even in Postman (only these API).

Thanks you for reply.

Answer (score 2):

After I go to bed and recheck my parameters again, I realize that I am missing some. It works now.

http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeHistory/v1?key={{key}}&language=en_us&format=json&max_trades=100&navigating_back=1&get_descriptions=0&include_failed=1&include_total=1

As you can see, I forgot max_trades and others that was cause of my problem.

Hope this help and sorry for my scatterbrain.